# MS Access 2019 - SQL alias on a column converts data to uppercase

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a strange situation ...

I have a Table with autoincrement field, a number field and a Short Text field all created with default properties

[image]

There are only 10 rows in the table and the first 5 rows look like this:

[image]

If I run the this query

```
SELECT Top 5 CustomerID, RegNo, TRIM(RegNo) AS xx
FROM Workordersxx
```

I get the following:

[image]

... as you would expect.

But if I change the query to

```
SELECT Top 5 CustomerID, RegNo, TRIM(RegNo) AS xxx
FROM Workordersxx
```

(Note the alias is now "xxx"), I get this:

[image]

... with the aliased column now in uppercase.

For clarity, I changed the SQL to show all columns and all rows.

SELECT WorkorderID, CustomerID, RegNo, TRIM(RegNo) AS xxx
FROM Workordersxx

[image]

Note that there are no indexes on this table
What am I missing here?

Comment: One possibility is that you have duplicates in the table.  Without an `order by`, the results can be in any order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, don't think record order is issue. Cannot replicate issue with Access 2010.

Comment: @June7 . . . I cannot think of a mechanism that would explain how changing the alias would change the values in the columns.  The only thing I can think of is that the returned results are not from the same rows, which is a possibility without an `order by`.

Comment: I know there is no guarantee same records would return, but still expect both queries to show same output. I added duplicate records with upper case and still can't replicate. Include WorkorderID in query. Which records do you consider 'TOP' - the most recent entered by WorkorderID?

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff. Thanks for your reply.
As you can see from the SQL I am showing the same field from a row twice, once with an alias. So the order of the records is not relevant since the problem occurs within each row. AlsoI am using Access 2019. (I should have said that in my question)

Comment: Hi June7. Thanks for your reply.
Since you can see from the SQL I am showing the same field from a row twice, once with an alias, so the problem occurs within each row. regardless of order

Comment: in select `SELECT Top 5` queries you should also add `WorkOrderId` column to verify if both the queries return the same rows.

Comment: What would `SELECT WorkorderID, CustomerID, RegNo, TRIM(RegNo) AS xxx, TRIM(RegNo) AS abc FROM Workordersxx` output?

Comment: Thanks to all that contributed to this.
I have not been able to find the cause of this and so I have had to check for case in code.

I will close this item now.
If anyone comes across this in the future and has a solution please post a comment here.
THanks, James